# Type Error: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the issue with my code?Keep getting

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"*
```

```
ata2 = [{'one': 1, 'two': 2}, {'one': 5, 'two': 10, 'three': 20}]


pd.DataFrame(ata2,index=['a','b'],columns=['one','two','three'])

ata2['four']=ata2['one']* ata2['two']
```

Comment: Is the `ata2` after the first declaration a typo mistake?

Comment: It was to call the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do a column multiplication, you need to set the `ata2` as a `pd.DataFrame`, so, you need this : `ata2 = pd.DataFrame(ata2,index=['a','b'],columns=['one','two','three'])`

Otherwise, `ata2` is still a `list`, instead of a `DataFrame` - and you can only access a list by using the indices which are `int`!